# getting the next element with xpath

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have the following html block, I'm trying to get all the city links under Alabama in this case. This is the xpath I have constructed

```
//h3/a[contains(text(),'Alabama')]/following::ul/li/a
```

But The xpath above matches too many things. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
<div class="geoUnit">

                <h3><a href="http://example.com/" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Alabama</a></h3>
                  <ul style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
                    <li style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><a href="http://example.com/" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Auburn</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com/">Birmingham</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com/">Dothan</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com/">Gadsden</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com/">Huntsville</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com/">Mobile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com/">Montgomery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com/">Muscle Shoals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://example.com/">Tuscaloosa</a></li>
                 </ul>
</div>
```

I want the following to be selected as an array in this case. I want to extract each city link. I am using xpath inside of Java

```
                    <li style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><a href="http://example.com/" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 

0);">Auburn</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://example.com/">Birmingham</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://example.com/">Dothan</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://example.com/">Gadsden</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://example.com/">Huntsville</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://example.com/">Mobile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://example.com/">Montgomery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://example.com/">Muscle Shoals</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://example.com/">Tuscaloosa</a></li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to get all the city links under Alabama in this case.

Your XPath does select all `a` that follow the targeted heading.

> But The xpath above matches too many things.

Perhaps there are additional `ul` elements following the targeted heading in your complete document.  In this case, you can append a `[1]` to the `ul` step in your XPath to limit the selection to the immediately following `ul` element:

```
//h3/a[contains(text(),'Alabama')]/following::ul[1]/li/a
```

or, cleaned-up a bit:

```
//h3[a='Alabama']/following-sibling::ul[1]/li/a
```

This will limit the `a` elements to those of just the immediately following `ul`.